# Is there a better way than this, to build an object from a data set?

Tags: javascript

If I have,

```
const data = [
    { fieldA: 'a', fieldB: 1 },
    { fieldA: 'b', fieldB: 2 },
    { fieldA: 'c', fieldB: 3 },
]

const getRequiredDataForField = (data, field) => {
    const result = {};
    data.forEach(element => result[element[field]] = element[field]);
    return result;
}
```

I can achieve what I want by doing,

```
console.log(getRequiredDataForField(data, 'fieldB'));

// output:
// {
//    1: 1,
//    2: 2,
//    3: 3,
// }
```

I feel like this is an inefficient approach — is there a better approach?

Comment: Your approach is perfectly fine. The strange output is what intrigues me. May I ask for what purpose a key and value be the same?

Comment: I may change up the logic, but I want to build the `lookup` object for a [table](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable). I tested out some hardcoded values, and it seems to work the same way as the docs suggest in their example (`{ 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' }`). So, I guess having something as, in my case, `{ 'red': 'red', 'blue: 'blue' }` would be a feasible approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach looks fine to me, but if you want a more functional approach, you can use `Object.fromEntries` to map the `fieldB` to an array with two copies:

```js
const data = [
    { fieldA: 'a', fieldB: 1 },
    { fieldA: 'b', fieldB: 2 },
    { fieldA: 'c', fieldB: 3 },
]

const getRequiredDataForField = (data, field) => Object.fromEntries(
  data.map(d => [d[field], d[field]])
);
console.log(getRequiredDataForField(data, 'fieldB'));
```

Comment: Your approach is about 25% faster than mine. Thank you, I'll use yours.

Comment: How is it 25% faster than yours @MikeK? Could you explain it?

Comment: I ran it with `console.time(..)` and `console.timeEnd(..)` and my approach was 0.2ms, his was about a consistent 0.15ms

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  { fieldA: "a", fieldB: 1 },
  { fieldA: "b", fieldB: 2 },
  { fieldA: "c", fieldB: 3 },
];


const getRequiredDataForField = (data, field) =>
  data.reduce((a, c) => ({ ...a, [c[field]]: c[field] }), {});


console.log(getRequiredDataForField(data, 'fieldB'))
console.log(getRequiredDataForField(data, 'fieldA'))
```

Comment: The ternary operator is redundant here, you could just `data.reduce((a, c) => ({ ...a, [c[field]]: c[field] }), {});` because there's always a `c[field]`